# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property textInput has not been initialized"

Tags: kotlin

i am new to android development and i am trying to run a open source app in my phone but it crashes, 
**the error i got is**

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property textInput has not been initialized
        at org.ligi.survivalmanual.ui.MainActivity.access$getTextInput$p(MainActivity.kt:50)
```

**the error hitting area in mainactivity**

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {


    private val drawerToggle by lazy { ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, drawer_open, drawer_close) }

    private val survivalContent by lazy { SurvivalContent(assets) }

    private lateinit var currentUrl: String
    private lateinit var currentTopicName: String


    private var lastFontSize = State.getFontSize()
    private var lastNightMode = State.nightModeString()
    private var lastAllowSelect = State.allowSelect()
    private lateinit var textInput: MutableList<String>

    private val linearLayoutManager by lazy { LinearLayoutManager(this) }
```

i came to know that i should **do a git submodule init/update** from [github](https://github.com/ligi/SurvivalManual/issues/54), but still not sure how to do that, please somebody help to make this app run!!please....I'm new to android!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal in the project's root folder (it should be called 'SurvivalManual' if you cloned it from the github) and execute:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Rebuild the project.

Comment: i tried what you mention what i get is "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" i tried to go to the exact git repo which i found in [this github](https://github.com/ligi/SurvivalManual/tree/master/.git-crypt)  is that right? am i using `git submodule init` in right place?